# Android:What is LayoutAnimation?

Tags: android

I am working on implementing simple animations on Android development and being successful. I came across one called 'LayoutAnimation'. I couldn't figure out exactly what it is and how can we implement it? Could someone explain me (or) give me link to know about 'LayoutAnimation' and How can we implement it step by step procedures?

Thank you for your helps in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

LayoutAnimationController can be used to control the animation of a view's children, as described in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just read this. I want samples to implement in code and resource step by step.

Comment: I found an example in "Pro Android" beginning on page 204 on google books: http://books.google.com/books?id=HQ1mG3FIEgoC&pg=PA204&dq=layoutanimation+android&ei=hPa8S7jJI5WuNsDI4esH&cd=1#v=onepage&q=layoutanimation%20android&f=false .